# Create a button like the Facebook "like" button in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I would like to create a button with the name "Participate" that works like the "like" button on facebook.

I have an contenttype called Event, which should show the participate button, that logged in users can click, and add themselves to the event.

When looking at the content for Event I would also like to display a list of the users which have clicked the Participate button.

Is there someone who can help me with how it can be solved or what i should look into?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this module with some php knowledge you can make it , **it's not what you really want** but this guys pushed the hard part

> The Activity module keeps track of the
>   things people do on your site and
>   provides mini-feeds of these
>   activities in blocks, in a specialized
>   table, and via RSS. The module is
>   extensible so that any other module
>   can integrate with it. The messages
>   that are produced are customizable via
>   the admin interface and are context
>   sensitive. Some theoretical example
>   messages include:
>
> - You wrote a comment in response to    "example comment title"
> - Jim wants to be your friend. Approve    this friendship here
> - Nancy is Phil's latest fan

http://drupal.org/project/activity